# Pasting text one line up in Vim

Tags: vim, paste

I often want to paste the text one line up from the current line. To do that, I currently use `0` and then `P`.

Is there any way to do this without `0` (e.g. without having to go to the beginning of the line)?

Comment: if your yanked text has linebreak, i.e. yanked by `Y`, you dont need the `0`, just `P`, vim paste yanked line above your current. If your yanked text doesn't have linebreak, `0` doesn't make sense either.  If this doesn't answer your question, please provide an example.

Comment: How did you "copy" the text you want to paste?

Answer (score 0):

If the register you are about to paste already contains full line(s) (i.e. is of *linewise* type), `P` will automatically paste above the current line. Positioning of the cursor is only necessary for *characterwise* (or *blockwise*) contents. (And then you still would have to insert a newline character to get a new line).)

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) provides `glp` / `glP` mappings (and several more variants) which enable you to "force" linewise paste, even on incomplete lines. The mappings provided by the plugin aren't shorter than the built-in commands, but they eliminate the mental burden of remembering the register type, and allow you to instead focus on the result ("I want this register in a new line") instead.